# How to properly write an .onclick() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, onclick, python-turtle

I am attempting to create a counter that updates every time the button is clicked. (This is my first solo program.) There seems to be a problem with the .onclick() function I have written, and I am unsure of what's wrong.

Here is my code for reference. . .

Thank you for your help.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Button Counting")
wn.bgcolor("red")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

written = 0

def click(x, y):
    wn.update()
    x = 0
    y = 0
    written += 1
    pen.clear()
    pen.write(" {} ".format(written), align="center")

button = turtle.Turtle()
button.penup()
button.color("white")
button.shape("square")
button.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=5)
button.onclick(click)

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("black")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 0)
pen.write(" 0 ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is down below.
This is one solution:

```
import turtle

written=0

wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Button Counting")
wn.bgcolor("red")
wn.setup(width=800,height=800)

button=turtle.Turtle()
button.penup()
button.color("white")
button.shape("square")
button.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=5)

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("black")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 0)
pen.write(" 0 ")

def click(x,y):
    global written
    wn.update()
    written += 1
    x=0
    y=0
    pen.clear()
    pen.write(" {} ".format(written), align="center")

turtle.listen()
button.onclick(click)
turtle.mainloop()
```

When using `turtle.onkey`/`turtle.onclick`etc you need to make the turtle first listen by doing `turtle.listen()` and then you add `button.onclick(click)`then `turtle.mainloop()` because if you don't add it, the program would immediately stop.
The changes I made were removing`wd.tracer(0)`because then it would hide the "button" adding `turtle.listen() button.onclick(click) turtle.mainloop()` and adding `global written` to the define `click` because you are changing the value of `written` in the define .If you have any questions just ask!

Comment: In this context, your use and explanation of `listen()` is bogus.  It's for keystrokes, not mouse clicks.  Also note that `pen.write(" 0 ")` is never seen when your code runs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @JonathanDrukker that two key issues are your misuse of `tracer()` and `update()`, which aren't even needed in this program, and the missing `global` declaration for `written`.  However, his initial issue with respect to `listen()` is a red herring as it only applies to keystrokes, not mouse clicks.  The necessity for `mainloop()` depends on your Python environment.

I'd go with a simpler implementation as adding spaces to a centered string does little of value, and `speed()` is of no real use in this context:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

written = 0

def click(x, y):
    global written

    written += 1
    pen.clear()
    pen.write(written, align='center')

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.title("Button Counting")
screen.bgcolor('red')

button = Turtle()
button.shape('square')
button.shapesize(5)
button.color('white')
button.onclick(click)

pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.write(written, align='center')

screen.mainloop()
```

However, this program, like your original and Jonathan's example, is fragile as it writes in the same place that a turtle is visible.  Slight changes to the code could cause it to stop working if the turtle is on top.  I would move the pen to somewhere like `(100, 100)` so that it isn't in the middle of another turtle.